# UTF 8 in preg_match

Tags: php, regex

sorry for my English.
I’m trying to use preg_match with utf-8 in PHP.

```
preg_match("/\bjaunā\b Iel.*/iu", "Jaunā Iela");
```

Function returns 0. But

```
preg_match("/\bjauna\b Iel.*/iu", "Jauna Iela");
```

works fine. 
Why?
Thanks.

Comment: First regexp works just fine for me.

Check encoding of your source file. 

Optionally, check server locale.

Comment: because word boundaries don't work correctly with special chars. In the text `Jaunā Iela` the word bounderies are: `\bJaun\bā \bIela\b`.

Comment: Which version of PHP is used?

Comment: Works fine, [here](http://ideone.com/3WxfnH)

Comment: [use PHP 5.3.4 or higher](http://3v4l.org/22Gf5).

Comment: I'm using PHP version 5.3.3 and Linux OS and I can't change PHP

Answer (score 1):

Word boundaries don't work correctly with special chars. In the text `Jaunā Iela` the word bounderies are: `\bJaun\bā \bIela\b`

So instead of using word bounderies, try a look-ahead and look-behind assertion for a space. (or beginning of string)  Like so:

The regex:

```
(?<=^|\s)Jaunā(?=\s) Iel.*
```

PHP:

```
preg_match("/(?<=^|\s)Jaunā(?=\s) Iel.*/i", "Jaunā Iela");
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/tV6yR9

Comment: Not sure why, but adding `u` option seems to return a match, at least in PopoFibo's code on ideone.

Comment: hmmm, yes interesting..  Maybe the OP is using early version of php..  the `u` modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. Maybe..  I don't know just a thought.  Either way, my answer above would be a workaround.  :)

Comment: Thanks you, but your answer don't working with numbers...
/(?<=^|\s)1(?=\s)/iu

Comment: Here, try this: `/(?<=^|\s)1(?=\s|$)/`.

Comment: Thanks, but your aproach dont help in situations like this:
preg_match("/(?<=^|\s)Jaunā(?=\s) Iel.*/i", "Think.Jaunā Iela")

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that would not match.  If you want to allow `.`periods to also be word separators, then you would use `(?<=^|\s|\.)Jaunā(?=\s|\.|$)`.

Comment: But if I wan all boundaries? "!?,. " etc

Comment: Well, then u can just add them into a char set, like so: `(?<=^|[\s!?,.])Jaunā(?=[\s!?,.]|$)`.  But why would you want this? Is there not spaces between your words? Or not spaces after punctuation?  What exactly are you trying to do?